# Update the metatag in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, yoast

Currently I am using Yoast plugin for seo. By default it assigns this meta tag for author page:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow,noodp"/>
```

How can I update this tag to:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow,noodp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `wp_head` hook and overwrite the meta tag by adding the following code to your [functions.php file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained)

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_in_head', 11 ); 
function insert_in_head(){
 echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow,noodp1"/>';
}
```

Comment: file name is functions.php

Comment: What are those 2 tags you mentioned in echo statement. I want to replace meta tags as I questioned above.

Comment: sorry for two line but i have changed the value earlier in your content section

Comment: @AkshayShah your code add meta noindex,follow in all pages

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to your WordPress website. When you’re logged in, you will be
   in your ‘Dashboard’. On the left-hand side, you will see a menu. In
   that menu, click on ‘SEO’.
2. The ‘SEO’ settings will expand providing you additional options. If you don’t see the ‘Tools’ setting in your ‘SEO’ menu, please
   enable your advanced settings first. Yoast SEO > Dashboard (Advanced
   disabled) Menu with advanced settings disabled Enable advanced
   features
3. Click on ‘Tools’. Yoast SEO > Tools
4. Click on ‘File Editor’. This menu will not appear if your WordPress install has disabled file editing. Please enable file
   editing or edit the file through FTP.
5. Make the changes to your robots.txt file. If you do not have a robots.txt file, click the button to create it.

Source:

https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-to-edit-robots-txt-through-yoast-seo/